# How to set onClickListener for a button in the android soft keyboard?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-softkeyboard

There is a clear way to set an `onClickListener` for buttons like **`Done`** button or **`Next`** button using `OnEditorActionListener`. But how can I set an `onClickListener` for buttons like **`speaker`** or a button of a letter like the letter **`M`**?

---

So, after failing to use `setOnKeyListener`, I had a look at [keyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) at developer.android and found the following quote:

> As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting
>   text, there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will
>   generate a key event: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in
>   fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on
>   receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular,
>   the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any
>   application targetting Jelly Bean or later, and will only send events
>   for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications
>   targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software
>   input methods may never send key events regardless of the version.
>   Consider using editor actions like IME_ACTION_DONE if you need
>   specific interaction with the software keyboard, as it gives more
>   visibility to the user as to how your application will react to key
>   presses.

this quote exists without any way to overcome that, so ?!!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `onKeyListener` ? Example

```
mEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_M ){
        // Example for M key
        // Code...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

You can read more about KeyEvent and other key codes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).

Comment: Well, I already tried this way, I don't know the reason but it doesn't even enter the onClick method

Comment: Well, it entered the method only when I used Next or Done